# Inverting a derivative: convex conjugate and envelope theorem

Tags: derivatives, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I need your help to go through the following mathematical steps. I am completely new to the rules used below and any help would be extremely appreciated.

---

Consider the function $G(\boldsymbol{x}): \mathbb{R}^J \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $\boldsymbol{x}\equiv (x_1,..., x_J)$.

- $G(\cdot )$ is known: give me any $\boldsymbol{x}$ and I can tell you the value $G(\boldsymbol{x})$.
- We know that $G(\cdot )$ is convex.
- Fix $\boldsymbol{x}=\boldsymbol{x}^*$ and let 
  $$
  (1) \hspace{1cm}\frac{\partial G(\boldsymbol{x}^*)}{\partial x_j}=a^*_j \text{ }\forall j=1,...,J
  $$
  where $a^*_j\in \mathbb{R}$ is a (known) parameter $\forall j=1,...,J$ and $\boldsymbol{a}^*\equiv (a_1,..., a_J)$.

---

My objective is to recover $\boldsymbol{x}^*$ by "inverting" (1).

---

The source that I found uses the following steps:

A) Consider the function $\bar{G}(\boldsymbol{a}): \mathbb{R}^J\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ prescribed by
$$
\bar{G}(\boldsymbol{a})\equiv 
\begin{cases}
 \max_{\boldsymbol{\tilde{x}}} \Big(\sum_{j=1}^J \tilde{x}_j a_j- G(\boldsymbol{\tilde{x}}) \Big) & \text{if  $\sum_{j=1}^Ja_j\leq 1$} \\
 \infty & \text{otherwise}
 \end{cases}
$$
This is the Legendre-Fenchel transform or convex conjugate of $G(\boldsymbol{x})$ and we know that $\bar{G}(\boldsymbol{a})$ is convex.

Since $G(\cdot )$ is known, also $\bar{G}(\cdot)$ is known.

B) Let $\boldsymbol{x}^{\text{opt}}(\boldsymbol{a}): \mathbb{R}^J\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^J$ be the function delivering the (unique?) solution of 
$$
\max_{\boldsymbol{\tilde{x}}} \Big(\sum_{j=1}^J \tilde{x}_j a_j- G(\boldsymbol{\tilde{x}}) \Big)
$$
for every $\boldsymbol{a}\in \mathbb{R}^J$.

C) By the envelope theorem
$$
\frac{\partial \bar{G}(\boldsymbol{a})}{\partial a_j}=x_j^{\text{opt}}(\boldsymbol{a}) \text{ }\forall j\in \{1,...,J\}
$$

D) The source concludes that 
$$
\frac{\partial \bar{G}(\boldsymbol{a}^*)}{\partial a_j}=x_j^* \text{ }\forall j\in \{1,...,J\}
$$

E) Since $\frac{\partial \bar{G}(\boldsymbol{a}^*)}{\partial a_j}$ is known $\forall j\in \{1,...,J\}$, we have recovered $\boldsymbol{x}^*$.

---

My doubts:

(i) How do we know that only $\boldsymbol{x}^*$ satisfies (1)?

(ii) Which properties of $G(\cdot)$ are sufficient to go through the steps above (convexity, strict convexity, C1,...)? And could you highlight where do we use those properties?

(iii) Where do we use the convexity (strict?) of $\bar{G}(\cdot)$? Do we need other properties of $\bar{G}(\cdot)$ to apply the envelope theorem?

(iv) How can we go from (C) to (D)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $G: \mathcal H \rightarrow (-\infty,+\infty] $ be a function and $x \in \mathcal H$. Recall the definition of the subdifferential of $G$ at $x$, namely

$$
\partial G(x) := \{a \in \mathcal H | G(z) \ge G(x) + \langle a, z - x\rangle\;\forall z \in \mathcal H\}.
$$

Now, if $G$ is **convex and lower semi-continuous** (and so $G^{**} = G$, where $G^*$ is the Fenchel-Legendre convex conjugate of $G$), then the following characterization is classical (and easy to proof using the so-called [Fenchel-Young inequality](https://people.ok.ubc.ca/bauschke/Research/68.pdf))

> **Lemma.** $a \in \partial G(x) \iff G(x) + G^*(a) = \langle x,a\rangle.$

Since the RHS of above characterization is symmetric in $(G, x)$ and $(G^*,a)$, we immediately get

> **Corollary.** $a \in \partial G(x) \iff x \in \partial G^*(a),$

which is precisely what you wanted to show.

Comment: Thanks, is $x$ a specific point? (corresponding to the $x^*$ in my question?)

Comment: $x$ is any point and $a$ is any point in the subdifferential of $G$ at $x$. In particular, it holds for the points in your question.

Comment: Thanks, last few clarifications: (1) is $G^{**}$ the Fenchel-Legendre conjugate of $G^*$? (2) is convexity intended as strict convexity?

Comment: Also, how can I conclude my last step (using my notation):

$\frac{\partial G(\boldsymbol{x}^*)}{\partial x_j}=a^*_j \text{ }\forall j=\{1,...,J\}$ $\Rightarrow$ $\boldsymbol{a}^*\in \partial G(\boldsymbol{x}^*)$ $\overbrace{\Rightarrow}^{\text{Corollary}}$ $\boldsymbol{x}^*\in \partial \bar{G}(\boldsymbol{a}^*)$ $\overbrace{\Rightarrow}^{\text{?}}$ $\frac{\partial \bar{G}(\boldsymbol{a}^*)}{\partial a_{j}}=x^*_j \text{ }\forall j=\{1,...,J\}$

Comment: Your notation is not formal and in fact a bit confusion. For one, what do your precisely mean by $\frac{\partial G(x^*)}{\partial x_j}$ ? Is $G$ differentiable ?

Comment: $\frac{\partial G(\boldsymbol{x}^*)}{\partial x_j}$ is the derivative of $G$ wrto $x_j$ evaluated at $\boldsymbol{x}^*$ [assuming that it exists].

Comment: In that case, the subdifferential (a set!) of $G$ at any point reduces to a singleton contain its gradient at that point, i.e $\partial G(x) = \{\nabla G(x)\} = \left\{\left(\frac{\partial G(x)}{\partial x_1},\ldots,\frac{\partial G(x)}{\partial x_J}\right)\right\}$. However, differentiability of $G$ doesn't imply differentiability of the convex conjugate. For that, you need **strict convexity** of $G$.